# Determine a set on which a sequence of holomorphic functions converges

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the set in $C$ on which $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(\dfrac{1-e^{z}}{1+e^{z}}\right)^{n}$$
converges.

My thought was to solve the inequality $\left|\dfrac{1-e^{z}}{1+e^{z}}\right|<1$. I have two questions:1.Are these points satisfying this inequality all the points we find or there are some other one? 2.If the answer of the first question is yes,how to solve this inequality?

Comment: yes. and set $s = 1-e^z$ you get $|1+2/s| > 1 \implies  s = \frac{2}{re^{i \theta}-1}, r > 1$...

Comment: Try using the ratio test. To find the radius of convergence.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli That's not right. If that quantity equals 1, the series can't converge.

Comment: If the absolute value is $1$, it also doesn't converge.  The terms of a convergent series must go to $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh, my God. Time to delete my garbage and go to sleep!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|(1-w)/(1+w)|<1$ iff $w$ is in the open right half plane. This follows from basic properties of linear fractional transformations.

Comment: Or simple geometry: the distance to $1$ is less than the distance to $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write $$\dfrac{1-e^{z}}{1+e^{z}}=-\tanh \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)=w$$ which makes $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(\dfrac{1-e^{z}}{1+e^{z}}\right)^{n}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}w^n$$ which converges if $|w|<1$. If this condition is satisfied, then $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(\dfrac{1-e^{z}}{1+e^{z}}\right)^{n}=\frac{1}{1+\tanh \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}$$